# Polymer.Base.importHref and flaky network conditions

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

We're using `Polymer.Base.importHref` to load parts of our application when they become needed.

This works quite well, except when the network environment is flaky: if the first `importHref` for a specific page fails, then it will never start working for the same URI until the whole application is reloaded.

From what I understand this might be intentional: `importHref` creates a `link` element dynamically, and the browser should not load the same document twice when using `import` links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our current approach for this problem is to keep track of failures in `importHref` per URI, and if a URI is requested that had seen failures we append something like `?retry=<counter>` to it.

This works quite nicely, with no ill effects so far.

Instead of loading elements lazily we also tried enabling "lazy registration", but that did not deliver the performance improvements we were hoping for alone. Both lazy-nesses work well together though.